# getting plist from documents directory instead of Bundle

Tags: iphone, nsarray, plist, nsdata

I'm trying to point to the documents directory instead of the Bundle, I have the following code:

```
    - (id)initWithLibraryName:(NSString *)libraryName {
         if (self = [super init]) {
             libraryPlist = libraryName;
             libraryContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                        pathForResource:libraryPlist ofType:@"plist"]];
```

I know I need to point the app to the documents directory using the following:

```
      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

My question is where do I insert this pointer in the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:libraryPlist ofType:@"plist"];
```

Is equivalent too:

```
[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[libraryPlist stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"]];
```

Except that the bundle call will return nil if the file does not exist.  You can use `fileExistsAtPath:` in NSFileManager to check if a file exists.

Comment: Do I still need to put in this:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

to point it to the right place?